# PHP Syntax not allowed

Tags: php

I would like to know why the syntax below cannot work with PHP. Anyone with an insight perhaps it does not make any sense or something.

```
($this->getState($state))->getEvent('eventOpen')->attach($observeCallback);
```

Basically the `getState($state)` method returns an object that within itself has both `getEvent($eventName)` and `attach($observerCallbackToAttach)`.

However, this throws an error and doesn't work.

Am I breaking the rules for thinking this is a valid syntax?

Comment: _"Am I breaking the rules for thinking this is a valid syntax?"_ Well obviously if php is throwing a error, then you are.

Comment: Does `getEvent()` method return the object ?

Comment: `returns an object that **within itself** has both getEvent($eventName) and attach($observerCallbackToAttach)`

Comment: In newer versions of PHP I believe it's valid.

Comment: Interesting how many times people claim "this throws an error" but are rather closemouthed about which one. :-)

Comment: @tekiv Yes it does return an object which has the methods getEvent() and attach(). Returning `$this` I believe is saying return the current object the call is being made on. However, in my case we already have an object as a return value.

Comment: The issue is that I am testing this with PHPUnit whith the command-line using PHP 5. I have PHP 7 installed perhaps I should see if I can change my versions at runtime to see if this would be okay with PHP 7 @Peter.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that `->attach($observeCallback)` runs on the *result* of `->getEvent('eventOpen')` -- not the result of `$this->getState($state)`.

Check what the `getEvent()` method returns. For this to work it needs `return $this;`.

Or else, clarify you code as such:

```
$tmp = $this->getState($state);
$tmp->getEvent('eventOpen');
$tmp->attach($observeCallback);
```

Or alternatively, move the `attach()` method to the class used in the object returned by `getEvent()`

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I just wanted to know as this looks acceptable in my eyes. However, I realized also that my command-line is not using PHP 7 only the web that I can switch to that version easily. Unless I am to change my PHP executable within my Environment Variables to see how PHP 7 will react.

Answer (score 2):

if the `getState` method returns an object which has 2 methods `getEvent` and `attach` then to make this work you have to return the same object with `getEvent` / `attach`. When you do `getEvent()->attach()` you are using the return value of `getEvent` not `getState`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do to make this work is to return `$this` in your methods:

```
class Something
{
    function setState($state)
    {
        if ($state != '') {
            $this->state = $state;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    function setUberState($uberState)
    {
        if ($uberState != '') {
            $this->uberState = $uberState;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Using the above class you should be able to do:

```
$something = new Something();
$object = $something->setState('state')->setUberState('uberstate');
```